# How to append to a list in on conflict_do_update in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

Model:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = "example"

    create_time = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    time_stamps = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(DateTime)), server_default="{}")
    update_time = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
```

Now when I insert new example, I need to append the `create_time` of new example into the `time_stamps` ARRAY, then I need to sort it to get the newest time and that time set as a new `update_time`.

I managed to do it separately

```
def update_record(db: Session, create_time: datetime, db_record: Example):
    db_record.time_stamps.append(create_time)
    sorted_times = sorted(db_record.time_stamps, reverse=True)
    db_record.update_time = sorted_times[0]
    db_record.time_stamps = sorted_times
    db.commit()
```

But I need to do it atomically using `INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE` clause.

So far I have:

```
db_dict = {"create_time": record.create_time,
          "time_stamps": [record.create_time],
          "update_time": record.create_time}

stm = insert(Example).values(db_dict)
do_update_stm = stm.on_conflict_do_update(constraint='my_unique_constraint',
                                         set_=dict(??)
```

My question is how to access and append to values of the original conflict row in `set_` inside `conflict_do_update` in SQLAlchemy?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to add values that were not added during the insert step.
`stm.on_conflict_do_update(constraint='my_unique_constraint', set_={"time_stamps": Example.__table__.c.time_stamps + text("EXCLUDED.time_stamps")})`

Comment: or
`stm.on_conflict_do_update(constraint='my_unique_constraint', set_={"time_stamps": Example.__table__.c.time_stamps + stm.excluded[Example.time_stamps.name]})`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I bypassed SQLAlchemy by writing a textual query where I could use this syntax to append to ARRAY

```
.. DO UPDATE SET time_stamps = example.time_stamps || EXCLUDED.create_time,
```